# Nvidia settings not working after system update

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display

my nvidia-settings application stopped working after I updated Ubuntu 12.04 a while ago.

when I do any changes in the application and hit "Apply", the application just exit and the changes are not carried out. An example of a change is disabling a secondary monitor.

this is the log from one attempt:

```
$ nvidia-settings 

ERROR: Error querying target relations

Gtk-Message: (for origin information, set GTK_DEBUG): failed to retrieve property `GtkOptionMenu::indicator-size' of type `GtkRequisition' from rc file value "0" of type `glong'
Gtk-Message: (for origin information, set GTK_DEBUG): failed to retrieve property `GtkOptionMenu::indicator-spacing' of type `GtkBorder' from rc file value "0" of type `glong'
The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 1106 error_code 2 request_code 139 minor_code 25)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

*I use a Lenovo W520 with nvidia-current. System is up to date, 304.116*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your ubuntu update also included some kernel upgrades, you know new linux-headers, new linux-image and so on. If that is what happened then all you need to do is to reinstall nvidia drivers to match your new kernel configuration. This is one of the most common issues when performing ubuntu updates and kernel upgrades after a fresh install.

Comment: I disagree that when you perform a Kernel update you need to reinstall the Nvidia drivers. If you install the Nvidia package from the archives, they should work seamlessly even after a kernel update. This has been my experience for the past year (both with Nouveau and proprietary Nvidia packages)

Comment: I agree ... it happens